# Hide navigation from one entry but not others

Tags: craft3, lightswitch

I am looking to hide the main navigation for entries that have the lightswitch 'showMainNavigation' disabled. The problem I am facing is when I disable for one entry, the navigation is hidden for all entries. Here is a sample of the code:

```
{% set mainEntry = craft.entries.slug(craft.app.request.getSegment(1)).one() %}
{% set menuLogo = mainEntry.menuLogo %}
{% set hideMenu = craft.entries.section('mysection').showMainNavigation('not 1').one() %} 

{% if hideMenu %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg main-menu">
    <div class="standard-wrapper">
        {% if menuLogo|length %}
        <div class="navbar-brand logo logo-white visible"><a href="#"><img src="{{siteUrl}}{{menuLogo.one().getUrl()}}"/></a></div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</nav>

{% else %}

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg main-menu">
    <div class="standard-wrapper">
        {% if menuLogo|length %}
        <div class="navbar-brand logo logo-white visible"><a href="#"><img src="{{siteUrl}}{{menuLogo.one().getUrl()}}"/></a></div>
        {% endif %}
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse float-right menu" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto no-list-style">
                <li class="nav-item active">list item 1</li>
                <li class="nav-item active">list item 2</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
</nav>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
{% set hideMenu = craft.entries.section('mysection').showMainNavigation('not 1').one() %}
```

will return the first entry that it can find in the section 'mysection' that has `showMainNavigation` off. So as soon as you disable it for one entry, `hideMenu` will 'return' true, whichever page you're on.

So to fix this, if `mainEntry` is your current entry, then replace the line by:

```
{% set hideMenu = mainEntry.showMainNavigation %}
```

Comment: Wow, I was really overthinking this! mainEntry is not the current entry but I used your example to fix this. {% set showMenu = entry.showMainNavigation %} then {% if not showMenu%}hide navigation{% else %}show navigation.